# Remove Event Listeners in Cesium

Tags: google-maps, event-handling, dom-events, cesiumjs

I searched quite a bit to find out the correct way to remove event listeners in Cesium. I believe the confusion I have is around whether to treat Cesium events as regular dom events (due to a lack of knowledge about events in general in javascript). I am creating a screen space event like below:

```js
    var handler = new Cesium.ScreenSpaceEventHandler(canvas);

    handler.setInputAction(function (movement) {
        var picked = scene.pick(movement.endPosition);
        if (Cesium.defined(picked) && picked.id === someEntity) {
            labelEntity.position = someEntity.position;
            labelEntity.label.show = true;
        } else {
            labelEntity.label.show = false;
        }
    }, Cesium.ScreenSpaceEventType.MOUSE_MOVE);
```

My question is, how can I remove this event? Is `handler.destroy()` removes all the event listeners associated with handler, or do I specifically have to remove event listeners by pointing to the cesium map dom element and calling `removeEventListener` on it? If that's the case, what parameters should be passed to `removeEventListener`?

Answer (score 0):

The parameters for [`removeInputAction`](https://cesium.com/learn/cesiumjs/ref-doc/ScreenSpaceEventHandler.html#removeInputAction) are just the `type` and optionally the `modifer`, and it looks like you're not using the modifier (SHIFT key, ALT key etc.)

So for the code you posted above, the removal would be:

```js
handler.removeInputAction(Cesium.ScreenSpaceEventType.MOUSE_MOVE);
```